# Detect the @ character or emails in discord.js

Tags: javascript, python, discord, discord.js

I want that when writing an email, the member is given a role in discord. But since I don't know how to do it, I tried this, the issue is that `if (message.content === "@"){` only works when I put `@`, I want it to include `@`, I couldn't do it with `If @ in message.content`, nor with neither `message.content.startswith` nor `contains`

FULL CODE

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const mySecret = process.env['token']

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("ready");
 });
 
client.on("message", message => {
  if(message.channel.id === "963510775215968266"){
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    
    if (message.content === "@"){
      message.member.roles.add("963515178174021642");
      message.author.send("Gracias por verificarte");
      message.delete();
    }
    else{
      message.author.send("¿Tienes problemas? Comunicate con un staff.");
      message.delete();
    }
  }
});

 
 client.login(mySecret);
```

If someone can give me a hand I would really appreciate it, I've been reading different pages for hours and I can't find the solution, or I just don't know how to apply it well

Comment: `Detect the @ character or mails` → What is attribute of email? is `hello bro@call.me` should be mail or `@` character?

Comment: You may use [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression) to determine email address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.includes()`

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const mySecret = process.env['token']

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("ready");
 });
 
client.on("message", message => {
  if(message.channel.id === "963510775215968266"){
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    
    if (message.content.includes("@")){
      message.member.roles.add("963515178174021642");
      message.author.send("Gracias por verificarte");
      message.delete();
    }
    else{
      message.author.send("¿Tienes problemas? Comunicate con un staff.");
      message.delete();
    }
  }
});

 
 client.login(mySecret);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can check if a substring is present with the [`in` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details).

In this case you can check for an "@" with:

```
if "@" in "my.email@example.com":
    print("String contains the @ character")
```

However, this is not a good way to do it, as any string with an "@" would be considered an E-mail.
A better way to check for an email is to use regular expressions or the [built-in `parseaddr(address)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.utils.html#email.utils.parseaddr) util.

In javascript (as your example) the method you're looking for is [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).

Example:

```
if ("my.email@example.com".includes("@")) {
  // your logic here
}
```

But here we have the same problem explained previously, and regex is a much better option (as already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/whats-the-best-way-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript))